# How to close or clean a stdout pipe?

Tags: go, ssh, stdout

I have a program which makes an ssh connection to a new (every time the program is executed) gcp instance to retrieve information. The problem is that sometimes I got this error and I don't know why:

```sh
2019/08/22 12:30:37 ssh: Stdout already set
```

My code(avoiding error handle):

```golang
results := /home/example.txt
client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", addrIP+":22", clientConfig)
session, err := client.NewSession()
defer session.Close()
data, err := session.Output(" cat " + results)
if err != nil {
    log.Print("Fails when new output")
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

During the output is when the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `session.Output` would set the `Stdout` of the session to a buffer, then run the command provided, and return the contents in the buffer.

If the `Stdout` of this session is already set (for example, if you call the `session.Output` multiple times), an error of "Stdout already set" will be returned.

If you need to run multiple commands in one session, just manually set the `Stdout` to some buffer maintained by yourself, and use the `session.Run()` method instead of `session.Output`.